# Facebook API allowing deauthorization of application

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

I know this question has been asked in the past, but times have changed and I am hoping the facebook SDK has progressed.  I have seen other websites with the ability to deauthorize their app from the website rather than having the user sign in to facebook to do it. An example is glassdoor.com. If you create an account and then sync your FB account you can then deauthorize on the Account page. Any ideas on how this works because I have searched facebook docs and find only the deauthorization callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In graph API you can issue an HTTP DELETE request to /UID/permissions to revoke authorization for an app. Or you can use auth.revokeAuthorization from legacy REST API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't investigated rest because it's marked on it way to deprecation. I could not find the graph equivalent so I used the rest api anyways.